# Wine system prolog

Tags: prolog, classification

I am having trouble with my code. At the moment, I want each wine to receive a point for a certain rule. I want the query in prolog dishes_wine_score([beef, fish], Wine,Score). Currently the code runs along all the wines and gives them one point but then does not doe anything with it. I need to add some sort of list that gives the wines a point and then this list has to be used on the second ingredient. Does someone know how to do this?

```
wine_color_body(riesling, riesling, white, _ ).
wine_color_body(sauvignon_blanc, sauvignon_blanc, white, light).
wine_color_body(viognier, viognier, white, light).
wine_color_body(pinot_grigio, pinot_grigio, white, light).
wine_color_body(pinot_blanc, pinot_blanc, white, _).

wine_color_body(cabernet_sauvignon, cabernet_sauvignon, red, light).
wine_color_body(malbec, malbec, red, light).
wine_color_body(pinot_noir, pinot_noir, red, medium).
wine_color_body(merlot, merlot, red, full).

%vis
dish_wine_score(fish, Wine, 1) :-
    wine_color_body(Wine, _ , white, _).
dish_wine_score(fish, Wine, 0) :-
    wine_color_body(Wine, _ , red, _).

dish_wine_score(baars, Wine, 1) :-
    wine_color_body(Wine, viognier, white, _).
dish_wine_score(baars, Wine, 1) :-
    wine_color_body(Wine, riesling, white, _).

%vlees
dish_wine_score(beef, Wine, 1) :-
    wine_color_body(Wine, _ , red, _).
dish_wine_score(beef, Wine, 0) :-
    wine_color_body(Wine, _ , white, _).

dish_wine_score(kalfsvlees, Wine, 1) :-
    wine_color_body(Wine, _ , red, _).


%saus
dish_wine_score(rode_wijn_saus, Wine, 1) :-
    wine_color_body(Wine, _ , red, light).


%groente
dish_wine_score(courgette, Wine, 1) :-
    wine_color_body(Wine, merlot, _ , _ ).



dishes_wine_score([], _Wine, 0).
dishes_wine_score([Dish | Dishes], Wine, Score) :-
    dish_wine_score(Dish, Wine, DishScore),
    dishes_wine_score(Dishes, Wine, RestScore),

    Score is DishScore + RestScore.

    higher_score(Dishes, Score1) :-
        dishes_wine_score(Dishes, _, Score2),
        Score2 > Score1.

    best_wine(Dishes, Wine, Score) :-
        dishes_wine_score(Dishes, Wine, Score),
        \+higher_score(Dishes, Score).
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

I have simplified the "wine_color_body/3" fact to not repeat the wine name. Looked unnecessary. The match between `courgette` and `merlot` can be done with:

```
dish_wine_score(courgette, merlot, 1).
```

And so:

```
wine_color_body(riesling           , white , _ ).
wine_color_body(sauvignon_blanc    , white , light).
wine_color_body(viognier           , white , light).
wine_color_body(pinot_grigio       , white , light).
wine_color_body(pinot_blanc        , white , _).
wine_color_body(cabernet_sauvignon , red   , light).
wine_color_body(malbec             , red   , light).
wine_color_body(pinot_noir         , red   , medium).
wine_color_body(merlot             , red   , full).

%vis
dish_wine_score(fish, Wine, 1) :- wine_color_body(Wine, white, _).
dish_wine_score(fish, Wine, 0) :- wine_color_body(Wine, red  , _).

dish_wine_score(baars, Wine, 1) :- wine_color_body(Wine, white, _).
dish_wine_score(baars, Wine, 1) :- wine_color_body(Wine, white, _).

%vlees
dish_wine_score(beef, Wine, 1) :- wine_color_body(Wine, red, _).
dish_wine_score(beef, Wine, 0) :- wine_color_body(Wine, white, _).

dish_wine_score(kalfsvlees, Wine, 1) :- wine_color_body(Wine, red, _).

%saus
dish_wine_score(rode_wijn_saus, Wine, 1) :-  wine_color_body(Wine, red, light).

%groente
dish_wine_score(courgette, merlot, 1).

dishes_wine_score([], _Wine, 0).

dishes_wine_score([Dish | Dishes], Wine, Score) :-
   dish_wine_score(Dish, Wine, DishScore),
   dishes_wine_score(Dishes, Wine, RestScore),
   Score is DishScore + RestScore.

best_wine(Dishes, Wine, Score) :-
   collect(Dishes,PairsSorted),
   format("All Scores: ~q\n",[PairsSorted]),
   PairsSorted = [Wine-Score|_].
   
collect(Dishes,PairsSorted) :-   
   setof(Wine-Score,        
        (wine_color_body(Wine,_,_),dishes_wine_score(Dishes,Wine,Score)),
        Pairs),
   sort(1,@>=,Pairs,PairsSorted).
```

Thus:

```
?- best_wine([beef,courgette,fish], Wine, Score).
All Scores: [merlot-2]
Wine = merlot,
Score = 2.
```

Comment: But I suppose you do want all wines listed?